# How do I exercise Formatters in tests using HttpServer?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

In my Web API app, I'm using `HttpServer` to contain my controller in unit tests, and I'm using `HttpClient` to call it directly, eg:

```
[Fact]
public void TestMyController()
{
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("default", "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

    var server = new HttpServer(config);
    var client = new HttpClient(server);

    var response = client.GetAsync("http://localhost/api/test/values").Result;
}
```

I've noticed (by stepping through the debugger, and confirmed on other SO posts), that the `JsonFormatter` is not really running - it's initialized, but not *exercised*.  Since this test isn't opening a socket, and the `HttpClient` is directly invoking the `HttpServer` through the `HttpMessageHandler` API, it does make sense that formatting/serialization isn't run because it's not needed.

In my case, I have some custom formatting/serialization/deserialization code that isn't being hit during these tests, but it's hit when I run in a real web server.  I'd like to exercise that code in these tests; and it also just seems risky to exclude the serialization/deserialization code path when testing.  Any advice on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is a quick example of what you could do to force formatters to go through serialization/deserialization. Here we are converting `ObjectContent` to `StreamContent`. In the below code, the call to `CopyToAsync` triggers a path where formatters are forced to serialize. In case of deserilization, in order to make sure we go through formatters we want the content to be of type other than `ObjectContent` as `ReadAsAsync` has internal logic which special cases `ObjectContnent` and we want to circumvent it.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new InMemoryHttpContentSerializationHandler(new HttpServer(config)));
```

---

```
public class InMemoryHttpContentSerializationHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    public InMemoryHttpContentSerializationHandler(HttpMessageHandler innerHandler)
        : base(innerHandler)
    {
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        request.Content = await ConvertToStreamContentAsync(request.Content);

        HttpResponseMessage response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        response.Content = await ConvertToStreamContentAsync(response.Content);

        return response;
    }

    private async Task<StreamContent> ConvertToStreamContentAsync(HttpContent originalContent)
    {
        if (originalContent == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        StreamContent streamContent = originalContent as StreamContent;

        if (streamContent != null)
        {
            return streamContent;
        }

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        await originalContent.CopyToAsync(ms);

        // Reset the stream position back to 0 as in the previous CopyToAsync() call,
        // a formatter for example, could have made the position to be at the end
        ms.Position = 0;

        streamContent = new StreamContent(ms);

        // copy headers from the original content
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>> header in originalContent.Headers)
        {
            streamContent.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(header.Key, header.Value);
        }

        return streamContent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just call response.Content.LoadIntoBufferAsync().Wait ?

Comment: `LoadIntoBufferAsync` would cause only serialization to go through formatters...but if we want to exercise the formatter deserialization too then the content type has to be different than `ObjectContent` due to the special casing that `ReadAsAsync` has where it just does retrieves the `.Value` of the object content..

Comment: Excellent answer - thank you very much.  I found your related blog post:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kiranchalla/archive/2012/05/06/in-memory-client-amp-host-and-integration-testing-of-your-web-api-service.aspx

In your answer posted here, the class is updated to use async/await.

Comment: @crimbo: I messed up accepting your edit...can you submit again?