# Post complex type to web api action works only with fiddler but not in the integration test

Tags: asp.net-web-api, integration-testing

In my integration test the object schoolyearCreateRequest sent to /api/schoolyears url contains only null values when passing to the `Post([FromBody] SchoolyearCreateRequest request)` action parameter.

But when I use fiddler:

```
http://localhost:6320/api/schoolyears
Content-Type: application/json
Request Body: 
{ SchoolyearDto:  
   { Id: 10 }
}
```

Then it works and the SchoolyearDto is not null.

What is the problem in my integration test?

```
var schoolyearCreateRequest = new SchoolyearCreateRequest
{
    SchoolyearDto = new SchoolyearDto(),
    SchoolclassCodeDtos = new List<SchoolclassCodeDTO>(),
    TimeTablesWeekAddedWeekA = new List<TimeTableDTO>(),
    TimeTablesWeekAddedWeekAB = new List<TimeTableDTO>()
};

// Arrange
const string url = "api/schoolyears/";
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, _server.BaseAddress + url);
request.Content = new ObjectContent<SchoolyearCreateRequest>(schoolyearCreateRequest,new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

// Act
var response = _client.PostAsync(_server.BaseAddress + url, request, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter(), new CancellationToken()).Result;

// Assert
Assert.That(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created);
```

UPDATE:

I made it working now in my integration test too:

replace these lines:

```
request.Content = new ObjectContent<SchoolyearCreateRequest>(schoolyearCreateRequest,new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
```

with this line:

```
var postData = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(schoolyearCreateRequest), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

Why do I have to serialize the data by myself? And why is nearly nobody doing this approach with web api integration testing? All blogs I read showed the usage of the ObjectContent ??

Comment: Don't use that overload of PostAsync to send a HttpRequestMessage.  You should not need to pass in the formatter.

Comment: @DarrelMiller To make a post request in my integration test I found out when I do not use the HttpRequestMessage object AT ALL but instead using this: var content = new ObjectContent<SchoolyearCreateRequest>(schoolyearCreateRequest,new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"); THEN my complex type is not null anymore at the action parameter. Now I do this: var response = _client.PostAsync(_server.BaseAddress + url, content).Result; Is this maybe what you spoke of Darrel ? Then I did it accidently right :p

Comment: @Elisa: I updated my post with an example...hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at my answer in the following post:

[How do I exercise Formatters in tests using HttpServer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20873798/how-do-i-exercise-formatters-in-tests-using-httpserver/20874162#20874162)

Also, you can take a look at my blog post which was written long time back, but is still relevant:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kiranchalla/archive/2012/05/06/in-memory-client-amp-host-and-integration-testing-of-your-web-api-service.aspx

**UPDATE**:
Since there seems to be confusion around this, following is a complete example of an in-memory test. Its a bit crude but still should give you an idea.

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using WebApplication251.Models;

namespace WebApplication251.Tests.Controllers
{
    [TestClass]
    public class PeopleControllerTest
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://dummyhost/";

        [TestMethod]
        public void PostTest()
        {
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

            // use the configuration that the web application has defined
            WebApiConfig.Register(config);

            HttpServer server = new HttpServer(config);

            //create a client with a handler which makes sure to exercise the formatters
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new InMemoryHttpContentSerializationHandler(server));

            Person p = new Person() { Name = "John" };

            using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync<Person>(baseAddress + "api/people", p).Result)
            {
                Assert.IsNotNull(response.Content);
                Assert.IsNotNull(response.Content.Headers.ContentType);
                Assert.AreEqual<string>("application/json; charset=utf-8", response.Content.Headers.ContentType.ToString());

                Person recPerson = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Person>().Result;

                Assert.AreEqual(p.Name, recPerson.Name);
            }
        }
    }

    public class InMemoryHttpContentSerializationHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        public InMemoryHttpContentSerializationHandler(HttpMessageHandler innerHandler)
            : base(innerHandler)
        {
        }

        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            request.Content = await ConvertToStreamContentAsync(request.Content);

            HttpResponseMessage response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

            response.Content = await ConvertToStreamContentAsync(response.Content);

            return response;
        }

        private async Task<StreamContent> ConvertToStreamContentAsync(HttpContent originalContent)
        {
            if (originalContent == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            StreamContent streamContent = originalContent as StreamContent;

            if (streamContent != null)
            {
                return streamContent;
            }

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

            await originalContent.CopyToAsync(ms);

            // Reset the stream position back to 0 as in the previous CopyToAsync() call,
            // a formatter for example, could have made the position to be at the end
            ms.Position = 0;

            streamContent = new StreamContent(ms);

            // copy headers from the original content
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>> header in originalContent.Headers)
            {
                streamContent.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(header.Key, header.Value);
            }

            return streamContent;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just quickly browsed your links searching for StringContent but found nothing. How come that my 2-liner works but you offer a much longer code to read the same? Is it because you do not serialize for yourself and let the web api do it?

Comment: @Elisa: I am not clear what you mention here...where am i referring to StringContent? and also my posts are talking about both making serialization and deserialization go through formatters..can you clarify more?

Comment: You do not refer to StringContent. I made my test working by using StringContent and serialize the data for myself. Now I was hoping to find the usage of the StringContent in your links, but it seems you do not use it. I just need guidance wether it was a good idea/approach to use the StringContent in my integration test because YOU do NOT use it in the links you have posted here. :-)

Comment: @Elisa: Thanks...I would like to take a look at your code to see how you are implementing using StringContent. You should check if your implementation goes through BOTH serialization & deserialization of Formatters...that is if your implementation triggers the `ReadFromStreamAsync` and `WriteFromStreamAsync` of the formatters...i have detailed my reasons in the above 2 posts..hope that helps.

Comment: There is not much to look about the StringContent implementation its a one-liner. But when you check my comment to Darrel above you see I managed to make it work. Now my DTO which I pass to the server action is not null anymore because I do NOT use the HttpMessageRequest anymore for the overloaded PostAsync() method. If there is anything wrong what I do please let me know :)

Comment: What you are doing is fine...but again i think you are still not getting what i mean...read my SO post and the blog post to get things clear...

Comment: Got it now... I want to trigger the json formatter with its serialization/deserialization therefore I need the code you posted :-) I read your 1th link than it was clear thanks again. @Elisa shhhh...